# Page Requested is Unavailable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have several form pages built using AMPscript and html. These pages create forms to add or edit items within data extensions. Strangely as I've used and reused the existing forms as templates I have a new symptom I'd not seen before.

The mechanics include that a blank form is the first case, fill in the form and submit and you should return to the same page (posts to itself) but the content changes to simply verify you have added or edited "x". If fed with a GUID code via "RequestParameter" the page should fill in all fields with those of the record matching the supplied GUID code.

What is starnge is how on two of the newest versions of this form, when requested without the GUID the page displays as expected and will create a new record. But when the GUID is supplied, the page indicates "The page you have requested is unavailable!". I'd expect an error message indicating a bad function call or no record matching but unavailable?

I think it may help to understand what exactly causes an ET landing page to respond that the page is "unavailable" as opposed to a more specific "error" statement. Frustrated as other examples doing nearly the same thing are able to create, review and update the records with ease.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about query string issues, not anything specific to SFDC/ETMC..

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because a fellow worker helped me see my error and it was blindingly obvious once spotted. We're working within "application pages" to assure the pages are unavailable to the public. When assigning a parameter to an application page it is critical to know that the details following the address begin with the ampersand(&) not the question mark (?) as the (?) was assigned to identify the primary landing page address. Adding another (?) indicator sends the system off on a goose-chase and suggests that the page is unavailable rather than helping a parameter to SET a variable to view the page.

So detail pages can't be

https://members.exacttarget.com/Page.aspx?QS=1b900a09733a?GUID=kjbnde6

must be:
https://members.exacttarget.com/Page.aspx?QS=1b900a09733a&GUID=kjbnde6